# Javascript for loop by category

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops, for-loop

I have the following code looping through a set of tags to be put into a list:

```
    for(var i = 0; i < data.tags.length; i++) {
               var tag = data.tags[i];  
               var item = '<li><input type="checkbox" value="' + tag.id + '"><label class="disabled">' + tag.tag_name + '</label></li>';
               $('ul').append(item);
    }
```

Each tag however has one of three categories associated with it (tag.category) and I want to make a new list for each category.

How can I get only the unique categories and display the tags I want for each section like:

```
<h1>Category 1</h1>
<ul>
<li>tag</li>
<li>tag</li>
</ul>
<h1>Category 2</h1>
<ul>
<li>tag</li>
<li>tag</li>
</ul>
<h1>Category 3</h1>
<ul>
<li>tag</li>
<li>tag</li>
<li>tag</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - *Each tag however has one of three categories associated with it (tag.category)*

Comment: I sure hope you're wrapping that script in the proper tags

Comment: @user2994560, was your question answered? if so, mark an answer to accept it. if not, clarify what problems still exist.

Answer (score 0):

I imagine this is what you are attempting to do. Create a heading/list if it hasn't already been created for that category, then append the item... if that category already exists, just append to the existing one.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6rN2/) - I filled data.tags with data that I believe represents your real data. You will notice all of the tags get appended to the correct category list.

```
var $lists = $("#lists");
for (var i = 0; i < data.tags.length; i++) {
    var tag = data.tags[i];
    var item = '<li><input type="checkbox" value="' + tag.id + '"><label class="disabled">' + tag.tag_name + '</label></li>';
    if(!$lists.children("#"+tag.category).length) {
        $lists.append("<h1>"+tag.category+"</h1><ul id="+tag.category+"></ul>");
    }
    $("#"+tag.category).append(item);
}
```

**Note:** You might want to change the id's of the `ul` to something like `"category" + tag.category + "List"` just to prevent overlapping ID's if you have an ID on your page that could coordinate with a category name. If you do this, you will also need to change the selectors (`"#"+tag.category`) to match.

**Note2:** The above will work regardless of how many categories your `data` has. So if a new category becomes available, you won't need to modify the code. [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B6rN2/1/)

**Note3:** As I'm not sure how familiar you are with HTML/JS/JQuery, I thought I should point out that I created a container for the lists with an ID of `lists`. This is so that when we create a new list we have a place to put it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to track somehow which categories have already passed as I assume they may come in a different order. You can do so by using a categories object using the category as identifier making it easy to check if it came through in a previous iteration.

I made a quick jsfiddle, also it's quite crude as it uses the categories objeect to also store the html. Then in the end just iterate over that object to display each items under the right category.

```
var data = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'a',
        category: 'A'
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'b',
        category: 'B'
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        name: 'aa',
        category: 'A'
    }
];

var categories = {};

data.forEach(function(tag) {

    if (!categories[tag.category]) {
        categories[tag.category] = "<h1>" + tag.category + "</h1>";
    }

    categories[tag.category] += "<div>id: "+ tag.id +" - name: " + tag.name + "</div>";

});

var html = "";
var cat;

for (cat in categories) {
    html += categories[cat];
}

document.body.innerHTML = html;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JXmHr/